# MAAS Create Iso and Add Node

Tags: server, 14.04, maas, cluster, cobbler

(1) How can I add existing Ubuntu 14.04 server or desktop to Ubuntu 14.04 MAAS?

(2) Is there way to build MAAS ISO similar to Cobbler ISO?
http://www.cobblerd.org/manuals/2.6.0/3/2/6_-_Build_ISO.html

Thanks,

Comment: Any suggestions appreciated???